# What is the diff between default & manual in RESULT_CACHE MODE DEFAULT | MANUAL?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is the difference between `default` & `manual` in the following code snippet? (Oracle 11g)

```
alter table t_a result_cache (mode default);
```

and

```
alter table t_a result_cache (mode manual);
```

**Image:**

[image: user_tables.result_cache]

The user_tables.result_cache column has three possible values (Source E40402-18 Oracle Reference 11g)

Answer (score 4):

After scanning a lot of the 11g (this question was about 11g) documentation from Oracle regarding this, I think the answer should be: `alter table t_a result_cache (mode manual);` is not documented. The fact that it is accepted is either an Oracle bug or it is a documentation defect that it is not described. While it might (who outside of Oracle can really proof that?) behave 100% the same as `mode default`, I would not use it, and use the two modes on table level that are described in the documentation: `DEFAULT` and `FORCE`. `MANUAL` is a documented option only for the parameter `RESULT_CACHE_MODE`.

This is the best - 11g related - documentation from Oracle that I could find which covers both Result Cache Table Annotations (chapter 7.6.3.3) as well as the RESULT_CACHE_MODE Initialization Parameter (chapter 7.6.3.1): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/memory.htm#BGBCABED

**Edit: corrected the link**

Comment: user_tables.result_cache column may show three possible values (DEFAULT, FORCE, MANUAL) as shown in the image of the Oracle Reference 11g (11.2)

Comment: @MeeranMohideen great find. so the documentation is not only unclear but also contradicting itself...

Comment: Thanks! Oracle By Example gives the useful details about the result_cache.